# assign unique number to each row returned by regexp_split_to_table in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, rownum

I need below output for the regexp_split_to_table output: -

```
select  regexp_split_to_table ('a,b,c,d,e,f',',') expr
---------------------------------------------

rownum    expr
--------------
1          a
2          b
3          c
4          d
5          e
6          f
```

i tried using the row_number() function as well, but it is returning 1 for all the rows

```
select row_number() over (), regexp_split_to_table ('a,b,c,d,e,f',',')
```

```
rownum    expr
--------------
1          a
1          b
1          c
1          d
1          e
1          f
```

Answer (score 2):

That's what `with ordinality` is for:

```
select rownum, expr
from regexp_split_to_table ('a,b,c,d,e,f',',') with ordinality as t(expr, rownum)
```

The rownum ("ordinality") is the "index" of that element in the result of `regexp_split_to_table`

---

Note that using `string_to_array()` with `unnest` is typically faster as regexes are quite expensive:

```
select rownum, expr
from unnest(string_to_array('a,b,c,d,e,f',',')) with ordinality as t(expr, rownum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your current query in a CTE and then use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT REGEXP_SPLIT_TO_TABLE ('a,b,c,d,e,f', ',') expr
)

SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY expr) rownum,
    expr
FROM cte
ORDER BY expr;
```